# "Oops! Something went wrong." in the location field on Edit Profile & Settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

If I go to my Edit Profile & Settings page and hang around for a few seconds, this happens to the location field:

[image: weird error]

It only happens after a few seconds; the field looks normal on initial page load. After whatever this is kicks in, I can't type in the field any more. The JS console shows the following error message:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/2357112
```

Comment: I had the issue and wanted to change my location which was outdated. As a workaround, removing the "disabled" attribute from the text field will let you update your location. Though I'm not sure if that will cause other problems...

Comment: The error we're getting is the same - like the referer isn't allowed. But this hasn't changed. We're poking it with sticks, but this seems to be something Google has screwed up in whatever transition they're doing.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310959/cant-change-location-in-profile

Comment: @Nick why not just make the location field plain text and be done with it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard clean data helps a lot there, for people using SEDE, email in time zones not at odd hours, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I believe Google started rolling out API key requirement changes to the map API early... this is probably part of the fallout of that.

https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html

Answer (score 4):

We've been locking down our Google API keys (in response to the Google Maps Platform announcement) and it turns out that the JS autocomplete bits need access to both the Places API and JavaScript Maps API. I'd only switched on access to the Places API because a) metrics said we weren't using it and b) when I gave it a test run there were no issues. I flipped the switch and then left for the day.

I get back this morning and it's broken. Turns out there's a lag with credential changes \o/

It's fixed now, apologies for the inconvenience.